# Using redux-persist only in development environment

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-persist

I'm using `redux-persist` and it's great.

However, when I try to use it *only* in development, it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong here?

### store.js

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

let store;
let persistor;

// Show the Redux Devtools only in development mode.
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
  const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
  store = createStore(persistedReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
  persistor = persistStore(store);
} else {
  store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
}

export { store, persistor };
```

### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import App from './App';
import { store, persistor } from './store';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
  );
} else {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
  );
}

registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: Is it definitely 'development' and not 'DEV' or 'DEVELOPMENT'?

Comment: Yep! It works fine for the Redux dev tools.

Comment: did you figured out the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why it's not working for you but I solved this problem by changing the whitelist/blacklist config based on whether I wanted to persist the data or not! Also, you should see about the "nested persists" to give better control": https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

When you don't want to persist the store, just add a "whitelist" attribute to your config for one inconsequential value in the store like "loading".